# How to use Nvim-R with vim--plug

Tags: r, neovim

I'am new to using neovim and i'm facing some issues i can't solve.
Indeed i  installed the plug in and so when i'am trying to launch a .R file :

[nvim opening a R file()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZGz9.jpg)

Moreover, my actual R version is  4.2.1,
And my init.vim looks like :
[init.vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHfrz.png)

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.